# Manual for chemistry and system biology?

Tags: equations, learning

Does anyone know if there exists a LaTeX manual which focuses on chemistry and perhaps also system biology?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you'd want in such a text. The basics of LaTeX stay much the same, and at least in chemistry most of the 'specialism' consists of diagrams which I'd suggest may well be best created using an external tool.

Comment: All the manuals of all the packages listed here: [mychemistry.eu/known-packages](http://www.mychemistry.eu/known-packages/). Although -- that's probably overkill. But you should be able to find _some_ useful information there :)

Comment: Basically, concerning some "typography issue" like "chemical equations and molecule structures", the best thing to do is to go through a few manuals of a few packages, choose the one you like the most and become a master in using this one package step-by-step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest follow the tohecz's comment. In [www.ctan.org/keyword/physics](http://www.ctan.org/keyword/physics) there are a easy index of packages associated with the keywords of Chemistry, Biology (and Physics, obviously). Browsing in the directory of each package usually you can find a pdf manual (probably also in your hard disk).

Alternatively, go to [texcatalogue.sarovar.org](http://texcatalogue.sarovar.org/) and then to  [Topical index](http://texcatalogue.sarovar.org/bytopic.html)  and search for [Biology](http://texcatalogue.sarovar.org/bytopic.html#biology) or [Chemistry](http://texcatalogue.sarovar.org/bytopic.html#chem)

May be is also worth to mention the article
[LaTeX Tools for Life Scientists (BioTEXniques?)](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2007-4/senthil/senthil.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

To write chemical reactions there are several (chemtools, mhchem,...)
To write organic molecule reaction schemes, there is **Chemfig**. See figure below.

[image]

Conversion of pyruvate to acetyl-CoA

```
\documentclass[margin={2mm 2mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsmath,amsbsy}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\usepackage{xcolor}%black, blue, brown, cyan, darkgray, gray, green, lightgray, lime, magenta, olive, orange, pink, purple, red, teal, violet, white, yellow


\usechemmodule{orbital,newman}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}% per right to e left to
\tikzset{myedge/.style={->, -{Latex[#1]}}}

%------- para desenhar ligações linha-pontinhos
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{ddbond}{initial}
{
    \state{initial}[width=4pt]
    {
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{4pt}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{2pt}{2pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{4pt}{2pt}}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{4pt}{0pt}}
    }
    \state{final}
    {
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
    }
}
\tikzset{lddbond/.style={decorate,decoration=ddbond}}
\tikzset{rddbond/.style={decorate,decoration={ddbond,mirror}}}
%Exemplo: -[:30,2,,,rddbond]
%
\chemsetup[orbital]{
    overlay,
    opacity=1,
    p/color = blue!75,
    p/scale=3,
    %   p/half,
    s/scale=1.5
}
%
%  \chemnameinit{} % para evitar espaço grande entre molecula e seu nome
%
%   [2,,,,decorate,decoration=zigzag] OU [2,,,,decorate,decoration=snake] para "cortar" moleculas grandes
%
% marcadores de posição SEMPRE entre colchetes  Ex: @{a3}  @{z}
\setchemfig{atom sep=1.8em,  cram width = 2pt, cram dash width = 0.2pt, cram dash sep = 0.4pt, bond offset = 1pt}
%
%-------------------------------A R R O W -- x --  
%
\catcode`\_=11
\definearrow5{-x>}{%
    \CF_arrowshiftnodes{#3}%
    \CF_expafter{\draw[}\CF_arrowcurrentstyle](\CF_arrowstartnode)--(\CF_arrowendnode)%
    coordinate[midway,shift=(\CF_ifempty{#4}{225}{#4}+\CF_arrowcurrentangle:\CF_ifempty{#5}{5pt}{#5})](line@start)%
    coordinate[midway,shift=(\CF_ifempty{#4}{45}{#4}+\CF_arrowcurrentangle:\CF_ifempty{#5}{5pt}{#5})](line@end)%
    coordinate[midway,shift=(\CF_ifempty{#4}{135}{#4}+\CF_arrowcurrentangle:\CF_ifempty{#5}{5pt}{#5})](line@start@i)%
    coordinate[midway,shift=(\CF_ifempty{#4}{315}{#4}+\CF_arrowcurrentangle:\CF_ifempty{#5}{5pt}{#5})](line@end@i);
    \draw(line@start)--(line@end);%
    \draw(line@start@i)--(line@end@i);%
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#1}{0.5}+\CF_arrowstartnode{#2}{0.5}-\CF_arrowendnode
}
\catcode`\_=8
%
%--------------ARROW EM U MODIFICADA  -\lU>    ---------------------------------
\catcode`\_=11
\definearrow5{-lU>}{%
    \CF_arrowshiftnodes{#3}%
    \CF_expafter{\draw[}\CF_arrowcurrentstyle](\CF_arrowstartnode)--(\CF_arrowendnode)node[pos=0.1](Uarrow@arctangent){};% <-------- replaced [midway] with [near start]. Alternatively, use [pos=0.25] or any other value of your choice to fine tune the arrow position.
    \CF_ifempty{#4}
    {\def\CF_Uarrowradius{0.333}}
    {\def\CF_Uarrowradius{#4}}%
    \CF_ifempty{#5}%
    {\def\CF_Uarrowabsangle{60}}
    {\pgfmathsetmacro\CF_Uarrowabsangle{abs(#5)}}% ne prendre en compte que la valeur absolue de l'angle
    \expandafter\draw\expanded{[\CF_ifempty{#1}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF_arrowcurrentstyle}},-]}(Uarrow@arctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF_compoundsep*\CF_currentarrowlength*\CF_Uarrowradius,start angle=\CF_arrowcurrentangle-90,delta angle=-\CF_Uarrowabsangle]node(Uarrow@start){};
    \expandafter\draw\expanded{[\CF_ifempty{#2}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF_arrowcurrentstyle}}]}(Uarrow@arctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF_compoundsep*\CF_currentarrowlength*\CF_Uarrowradius,start angle=\CF_arrowcurrentangle-90,delta angle=\CF_Uarrowabsangle]node(Uarrow@end){};
    \pgfmathsetmacro\CF_temp{\CF_Uarrowradius*cos(\CF_arrowcurrentangle)<0?"-":"+"}%
    \ifdim\CF_Uarrowradius pt>0pt
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#1}{0}\CF_temp{Uarrow@start}{#2}{1}\CF_temp{Uarrow@end}%
    \else
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#2}{0}\CF_temp{Uarrow@start}{#1}{1}\CF_temp{Uarrow@end}%
    \fi
}
\catcode`\_=8
%----------------------------------------------
\catcode`\_=11

% Initial arguments:
% #1, #2: Same as for -U> (above arrow)
% #3: Additional label at midpoint (also above arrow)
% #4, #5, #6: Like #1, #2, and #3, but below arrow
% #7: Optional shift, default 0
% #8: Optional arrow radius
% #9: Optional arrow angle   
\definearrow9{-Z>}{%
    \CF_arrowshiftnodes{#7}%
    \expandafter\draw\expandafter[\CF_arrowcurrentstyle](\CF_arrowstartnode)--(\CF_arrowendnode)node[midway](Xarrowarctangent){};%
    \CF_ifempty{#8}
    {\def\CF_Xarrowradius{0.333}}
    {\def\CF_Xarrowradius{#8}}%
    \CF_ifempty{#9}%
    {\def\CF_Xarrowabsangle{60}}
    {\pgfmathsetmacro\CF_Xarrowabsangle{abs(#9)}}
    % Draw top arrow (start)
    \edef\CF_tmpstr{[\CF_ifempty{#1}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF_arrowcurrentstyle}},-]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF_tmpstr (Xarrowarctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF_compoundsep*\CF_currentarrowlength*\CF_Xarrowradius,start angle=\CF_arrowcurrentangle-90,delta angle=-\CF_Xarrowabsangle]node(Xarrow1start){};
    % Draw bottom arrow (end)
    \edef\CF_tmpstr{[\CF_ifempty{#2}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF_arrowcurrentstyle}},-CF]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF_tmpstr (Xarrowarctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF_compoundsep*\CF_currentarrowlength*\CF_Xarrowradius,%
    start angle=\CF_arrowcurrentangle-90,%
    delta angle=\CF_Xarrowabsangle]%
    node(Xarrow1end){};
    % Draw bottom arrow (start)
    \edef\CF_tmpstr{[\CF_ifempty{#4}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF_arrowcurrentstyle}},-]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF_tmpstr (Xarrowarctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF_compoundsep*\CF_currentarrowlength*\CF_Xarrowradius,start angle=\CF_arrowcurrentangle+90,delta angle=\CF_Xarrowabsangle]node(Xarrow2start){};
    % Draw bottom arrow (end)
    \edef\CF_tmpstr{[\CF_ifempty{#5}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF_arrowcurrentstyle}},-CF]}%
    \expandafter\draw\CF_tmpstr (Xarrowarctangent)%
    arc[radius=\CF_compoundsep*\CF_currentarrowlength*\CF_Xarrowradius,%
    start angle=\CF_arrowcurrentangle+90,%
    delta angle=-\CF_Xarrowabsangle]%
    node(Xarrow2end){};
    % Insert labels
    \pgfmathsetmacro\CF_tmpstra{\CF_Xarrowradius*cos(\CF_arrowcurrentangle)<0?"-":"+"}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\CF_tmpstrb{\CF_Xarrowradius*cos(\CF_arrowcurrentangle)<0?"+":"-"}%
    \ifdim\CF_Xarrowradius pt>0 pt
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#1}{0}\CF_tmpstra{Xarrow1start}{#2}{1}\CF_tmpstra{Xarrow1end}%
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#4}{0}\CF_tmpstrb{Xarrow2start}{#5}{1}\CF_tmpstrb{Xarrow2end}%
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#3}{0.5}\CF_tmpstra\CF_arrowstartnode{}{}{}\CF_arrowendnode%
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#6}{0.5}\CF_tmpstrb\CF_arrowstartnode{}{}{}\CF_arrowendnode%
    \else
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#2}{0}\CF_tmpstra{Xarrow1start}{#1}{1}\CF_tmpstra{Xarrow1end}%
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#5}{0}\CF_tmpstrb{Xarrow2start}{#4}{1}\CF_tmpstrb{Xarrow2end}%
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#3}{0.5}\CF_tmpstra\CF_arrowstartnode{}{}{}\CF_arrowendnode%
    \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#6}{0.5}\CF_tmpstrb\CF_arrowstartnode{}{}{}\CF_arrowendnode%
    \fi
}
% stop editting chemfig
\catcode`\_=8
%----------------------------------------------
% COMANDO PARA ESCREVER ALGO DENTRO DE UM "CARTUCHO"
\newcommand{\enz}{{\Circled[outer color=blue,inner color=blue,fill color=lime]{\textnormal{Enz}}}}
%
\newcommand{\sint}{{\Circled[outer color=blue,inner color=blue,fill color=lime]{\textnormal{Sintase}}}}
%
\newcommand{\enzi}{{\Circled[outer color=blue,inner color=blue,fill color=lime]{\textnormal{Lys}}}}
%
\newcommand{\aden}{{\Circled[outer color=blue,inner color=blue,fill color=lime]{\textnormal{Adenosina}}}}
%
\newcommand{\numer}{{\Circled[outer color=blue,inner color=red,fill color=yellow]{\textnormal{\Huge 1}}}}
\newcommand{\numero}{{\Circled[outer color=blue,inner color=red,fill color=yellow]{\textnormal{\Huge 2}}}}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}    
    %
    %\definesubmol{x}{(-[4]H)(-[0]OH)}
    %\definesubmol{y}{(-[0]H)(-[4]HO)}
    %
\begin{tabularx}{970pt}{l}  
%
\schemestart
%
\chemfig{[,1.5]^{-}O-[:30]C(=[2]O)-[:330]@{a2}C(=[@{a3}6]O)-[:30]CH_3}
%
\arrow{->}[0,1.5]
%
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\arrow(@{a3}--){0}[200,.6]\chemfig{@{a6}A-[@{a5},1.2]@{a4}H}
%
\arrow(@{a2}--){0}[150,2]\chemfig{[,1.5]S*5([:54]-(-R')=[@{z1}](-CH_3)-\chemabove{N}{\scriptscriptstyle+}(-R)=[@{w1}]@{a1}\charge{180=\:}{}(-[:150,.3,,,,draw=none]^{-})-)}
%
\arrow(@{w1}--){<-[\chemfig{@{bb1}\charge{90=\:}{B}}]}[180,1.5,shorten >= 10pt]\chemfig{[,1.5]^{-}OPOPOCH_2C(=[2,,3]O)(=[2,,5]O)(-[6,,3]O(\hspace{14pt}^{-}))(-[6,,5]O(\hspace{14pt}^{-}))(-[:355,.5,,,,draw=none]H_2)-[:60]*5([:54]=(-@{z42}CH_3)-\chemabove{N}{\scriptscriptstyle+}(-[:30]-[:330]*6(-=N-(-CH_3)=N-(-[2,1]NH_2)=))=(-@{bb2}H)-S-)}
%
%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\arrow(@{z42}--){0}[270,.4]\parbox{4cm}{\centering Tiamina difosfato (TPP)}
\arrow(@{z1}--){0}[0,.1]\parbox{5cm}{\centering Ilida de tiamina difosfato\\ (Ilida TPP)}
\arrow(@{a3}--){0}[270,.6]\parbox{2cm}{\centering Piruvato}
%
%============================================================================
\chemmove{     % myedge={right}   para meia seta 
    \draw[red,shorten <=3pt,shorten >=1pt](a1.200).. controls +(270:28mm) and +(90:46mm)..(a2);
    \draw[red,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=1pt](a3).. controls +(180:6mm) and +(90:6mm)..(a4);
    \draw[red,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt](a5).. controls +(90:6mm) and +(90:6mm)..(a6);
    %----------------------------------------------------
    \draw[red,shorten <=3pt,shorten >=1pt](bb1).. controls +(90:18mm) and +(0:36mm)..(bb2);
}
\schemestop
\\
\\
\\
\schemestart
%
\arrow{->}
%
\chemleft[
\subscheme{
%
\chemfig{[,1.5]^{-}\,@{b1}\charge{90=\:,180=\:,270=\:}{O}-[@{b2}:30]C(=[2]O)-[@{b3}:330]C(-[:240]HO)(-[:300]CH_3)-[@{b4}:30]*5([:36]-S-(-R')=(-CH_3)-@{b6}\chemabove{N}{\scriptscriptstyle+}(-R)=[@{b5}])}
%
\arrow{-lU>[][CO$_2$][][.5][60]}[0,1.5]
%
\chemfig{[,1.5]HO-[:330]C(-[6]@{z2}CH_3)=[@{d3}:30]*5([:36]-S-(-R')=(-CH_3)-@{d1}\charge{180=\:}{N}(-R)-[@{d2}])}
%
\arrow{->}[0,1.5]
%
\chemfig{[,1.5]@{e2}H-[@{e3}]O-[@{e4}:330]C(-[:240]H_3C)(-[:300]S-[6]-[:330]-[:30](-[:330]R')-[2]SH)-[@{e5}:30]*5([:36]@{e6}-S-(-R')=(-CH_3)-\chemabove{N}{\scriptscriptstyle+}(-R)=)}
%
\arrow{->}[0,1.5]
%
\chemfig{[,1.5]H_3C-[:30]C(=[2]O)-[:330]S-[:30]@{x1}-[:330]-[:30](-[2]SH)-[:330]R'}
%
}
\chemright]
%
\arrow{->}
%
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\arrow(@{d3}--){0}[100,1.5]\chemfig{[,1.5]@{d4}S*5([:36]--[@{z3}]-(-R')-S-[@{d5}])}
%
\arrow(@{d5}--){0}[150,1]\chemfig{@{d8}A-[@{d7},1.2]@{d6}H}
%
\arrow(@{e2}--){0}[120,.6]\chemfig{@{e1}\charge{0=\:}{B}}
%
\arrow(@{x1}--){0}[90,1.3]\chemfig{[,1.5]S*5([:54]-(-R')=[@{z41}](-CH_3)-\chemabove{N}{\scriptscriptstyle+}(-R)=\charge{180=\:}{}(-[:150,.3,,,,draw=none]^{-})-)}
%
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\arrow(@{z2}--){0}[270,.2]\parbox{2cm}{\centering HEPTT}
\arrow(@{z3}--){0}[0,.2]\parbox{2cm}{\centering Lipoamida}
\arrow(@{z41}--){0}[0,.2]\parbox{2cm}{\centering Ilida TPP}
%=======================================================================================
\chemmove{     % myedge={right}   para meia seta 
    \draw[red,shorten <=3pt,shorten >=1pt](b1).. controls +(90:8mm) and +(100:6mm)..(b2);
    \draw[red,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt](b3).. controls +(80:6mm) and +(100:6mm)..(b4);
    \draw[red,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt](b5).. controls +(180:6mm) and +(180:6mm)..(b6);
    %----------------------------------------------------
    \draw[red,shorten <=3pt,shorten >=1pt](d1).. controls +(180:8mm) and +(180:6mm)..(d2);
    \draw[red,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=1pt](d3).. controls +(150:16mm) and +(240:16mm)..(d4);
    \draw[red,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt](d5).. controls +(210:6mm) and +(270:6mm)..(d6);
    \draw[red,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt](d7).. controls +(90:6mm) and +(90:6mm)..(d8);
    %----------------------------------------------------
    \draw[red,shorten <=3pt,shorten >=1pt](e1).. controls +(0:8mm) and +(90:6mm)..(e2);
    \draw[red,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=1pt](e3).. controls +(80:8mm) and +(60:8mm)..(e4);
    \draw[red,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt](e5).. controls +(120:6mm) and +(130:6mm)..(e6);
}
\schemestop
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\schemestart
%
\hspace{8cm}
\arrow{->}
%
\chemfig{[,1.5]H_3C-[:30]@{f4}C(=[@{f5}2]O)-[:330]S-[:30]-[:330]-[:30](-[2]SH)-[:330]R'}
%
\arrow{->}
%
\chemleft[
\subscheme{
    %
    \chemfig{[,1.5]@{g2}H-[@{g3}]O-[@{g4}:300]C(-[:240]H_3C)(-[:300]SCoA)-[@{g5}:60]S-[0]-[:60]-[0](-[:60]SH)-[:300]R'}
    %
    \arrow(@{g2}--){0}[120,.6]\chemfig{@{g1}\charge{0=\:}{B}}
    %
    \arrow(@{g5}--){0}[70,1]\chemfig{@{g6}H-[@{g7},1.2]@{g8}A}
    %
}
\chemright]
%
\arrow{->}
%
\chemfig{[,1.5]H_3C-[:30]@{z5}C(=[2]@{x2}O)-[:330]SCoA}
%
%----------------------------------------------------------------
\arrow(@{f5}--){0}[150,.6]\chemfig{@{f6}H-[@{f7},1.2]@{f8}A}
%
\arrow(@{f4}--){0}[300,1]\chemfig{CoAS-[@{f3},1.2]@{f2}H}
%
\arrow(@{f2}--){0}[0,.6]\chemfig{@{f1}\charge{90=\:}{B}}
%
\arrow(@{x2}--){0}[90,1]\chemfig{HS-[:30]-[:330]@{z4}-[:30](-[2]SH)-[:330]@{x3}R'}
%
\arrow(@{x2}--){0}[90,.4]\+
%
\arrow(@{x3}--){-U>[FAD][FADH$_2$]}[0,1.5]\chemfig{[,1.5]*5([:-18]-@{z43}-(-R')-S-S-)}
%-------------------------------------------------------------
\arrow(@{z4}--){0}[270,.2]\parbox{3cm}{\centering Dihidrolipoamida}
\arrow(@{z43}--){0}[270,.4]\parbox{2cm}{\centering Lipoamida}
\arrow(@{z5}--){0}[270,.4]\parbox{2cm}{\centering Acetil-CoA}
%=======================================================================================
\chemmove{     % myedge={right}   para meia seta 
\draw[red,shorten <=3pt,shorten >=1pt](f1).. controls +(90:8mm) and +(90:6mm)..(f2);
\draw[red,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt](f3).. controls +(90:6mm) and +(270:6mm)..(f4);
\draw[red,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt](f5).. controls +(180:6mm) and +(270:6mm)..(f6);
\draw[red,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt](f7).. controls +(90:6mm) and +(90:6mm)..(f8);
%----------------------------------------------------
\draw[red,shorten <=3pt,shorten >=1pt](g1).. controls +(0:8mm) and +(90:6mm)..(g2);
\draw[red,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt](g3).. controls +(270:6mm) and +(240:6mm)..(g4);
\draw[red,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt](g5).. controls +(120:16mm) and +(180:16mm)..(g6);
\draw[red,shorten <=1pt,shorten >=1pt](g7).. controls +(90:6mm) and +(90:6mm)..(g8);
}
\schemestop
\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question. These packages are listed in @cgnieder's comment above. Also, the image you posted should contain a citation (unless you created it).

Comment: @SandyG  -- On mychemistry.eu there is a very short explanation of what each software does. I thought a demo of what the chemfig package does would be most helpful. Yes, this reaction scheme was created by me, like all the others I put here.